# Sandbox Paypal Pro is not working

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using using paypal pro to collect payment from customers credit card. for testing my script for recurring payments i have setup sandbox account with Pro option (Business - Pro). when i send api request to paypal with DoDirectPayment method, it respond me with this error.

```
["L_ERRORCODE0"]=> string(5) "10548"

["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]=> string(21) "Invalid Configuration" 

["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=> string(97) "This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions."
```

I have tried by using multiple sandbox accounts and even by creating new paypal account but it didn't work. i would really appricaite your help thank you.

[Sandbox Account Configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOgfQ.png) 
[Sandbox Account Configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ookzC.png)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have what I believe to be a similar issue.

Comment: same issue have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade business account to business pro from paypal admin login.

Comment: do i also need to upgrade paypal main account ? actually its dummy account. well let me check it.

Comment: you can upgrade business account from sandbox paypal as well. no need to make live account for it.

Comment: i have upgraded my sandbox paypal accounts as i have attached images above.